# adding comments form Django

Tags: python, django, comments

I am trying to add a form to my topics.html page so that a user can submit a comment. When the user submits the comment I want to display who posted the comment and the time and date (see image)

[image]

When I am submitting the data I am receiving the following error:

[image]

I believe it has to do with the fact that I am not specifying the user who's posting the comment properly.and also I'm not passing the current topic that the user is posting to.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from comments.models import Comment
from .models import Category, Entry, Topic
from .forms import CategoryForm, TopicForm, EntryForm, CommentForm


def topic(request, entry_id):
    """Show entry for single topic"""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=entry_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.all()
    comments = Comment.objects.all()

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No comment submitted
        form = CommentForm()
    else:
        # Comment posted
        form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogging_logs:topic'))

    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries, 'comments': comments, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'blogging_logs/topic.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['content']
        labels = {'text': ''}
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})}
```

**comments app: model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

from blogging_logs.models import Topic
# Create your models here.


class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Comment model has a Foreignkey to Topic and you didn't specify that it is allowed to be null. Then you have a form that creates Comment instances by putting something in the field 'content'. By definition this means that your topic field is empty or null, which is not allowed. Just add it similarly to how you add the user, i.e.

```
new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
new_comment.user = request.user
new_comment.topic = topic
form.save()
```